# Processing 1.5 million rows against each other

Tags: c#, sql-server-2008, preprocessor, sqlbulkcopy

I need to go through 1.5 million rows, for row I need to calculate a variance against all other rows.

At the moment I'm doing something like:

```
    // Mocked Data
    var myTable = new DataTable("hello");
    myTable.Columns.Add("ID", typeof (int));
    myTable.Columns.Add("Value", typeof(byte[]));
    var random = new Random();
    for (int i = 0; i < 1000; i++)
    {
        var row = myTable.NewRow();
        row["ID"] = i;
        var bitArray = new BitArray(50 * 50);
        for (int j = 0; j < 50*50; j++)
        {
            bitArray.Set(j, random.NextDouble() >= random.NextDouble());
        }

        byte[] byteArray = new byte[(int)Math.Ceiling((double)bitArray.Length / 8)];

        bitArray.CopyTo(byteArray, 0);

        row["Value"] = byteArray;
        myTable.Rows.Add(row);
    }
    // Mocked data complete.


    var calculated = new DataTable("calculated");
    calculated.Columns.Add("ID", typeof (int));
    calculated.Columns.Add("AaginstID", typeof (int));
    calculated.Columns.Add("ComputedIntersect", typeof(byte[]));
    calculated.Columns.Add("ComputedUnion", typeof(byte[]));
    for (int i = 0; i < myTable.Rows.Count; i++)
    {
        for (int j = i + 1; j < myTable.Rows.Count; j++)
        {
            var row = calculated.NewRow();
            row["ID"] = myTable.Rows[i]["ID"];
            row["AaginstID"] = myTable.Rows[j]["ID"];

            var intersectArray = new BitArray((byte[]) myTable.Rows[i]["Value"]);
            var unionArray = new BitArray((byte[])myTable.Rows[i]["Value"]);
            var jArray = new BitArray((byte[])myTable.Rows[j]["Value"]);


            intersectArray.And(jArray);
            unionArray.Or(jArray);

            var intersectByteArray = new byte[(int)Math.Ceiling((double)intersectArray.Length / 8)];
            var unionByteArray = new byte[(int)Math.Ceiling((double)unionArray.Length / 8)];

            intersectArray.CopyTo(intersectByteArray, 0);
            unionArray.CopyTo(unionByteArray, 0);

            row["ComputedIntersect"] = intersectByteArray;
            row["ComputedUnion"] = unionByteArray;
            calculated.Rows.Add(row);
        }
        // Real data is 1.5m+ rows, so need to do this incrementally
        // STORE DATA TO DB HERE
    }
```

I store my data using SQLBulkCopy with TableLock on, my BatchSize is default (0 - whole batch). Saving 1.5 millions records to the DB is a little slow (30/60 seconds), so I'm open to suggestions on changing up my SQL storage mechanism too, but the main bottleneck is the C#.  My BitArray is 2500 bits in size (I use 50*50 as it's a grid, in the code I allow for a variable grid size, for this test, assume it's always 2500 bits).

To process 1.5 million rows against a single row takes roughly 140 seconds, this would take too long to process everything, so I need to find a better way.  This much work is being done in order to pre-process the data for faster retrieval when it counts, so I COULD leave this going for a day, but from my calculations, this would take nearly three years to process...

I store the data to the DB on each loop of the outer loop so that I don't hold too much in memory at once.  The data is set up in an unrealistic way, I do use BitArray.Set for the first round of processing (to generate the 1.5 million rows), and that is a bottle neck, but that doesn't need revision.  The main goal is to get the Union/Intersection of each row against all others, so that later on I can just pull out the related rows, ready to go.  So if there is a better storage type (Binary(313) in the DB), or a better way to get the same result, I'm open to a rewrite.

I have considered writing a SQL CLR function, but I am not sure that is the right approach either.  Pre-pocessing the data is required, so I'm looking for help on the best approach.

Comment: 30 seconds seems reasonable to me.

Comment: That's 30 seconds just for the DB save, I know I can get that down by chunking it out, I could get the DB save down to 10 seconds or so (I've saved much more data in 30 seconds).  But the issue is the 140 (110 of c# running) seconds to process a single row.  It would take three years to complete, I don't have that much time! lol

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest doing all your computing in the database. SQL Server is best at set based operations which makes it perfect for theses types of problems. I brief idea of the steps you could take

1. bcp all your data into a temporary table.
2. Update the temporary table with the computed values you need.
3. Insert into your "real" table selecting the values you want from the temporary table.

Comment: How would you compute this type of data (binary intersect/union) in SQL Server?  How would you walk through all 1.5 million rows?  Steps 1.3 is pretty much what I'm doing now.  Step 2 is the "magic" step where I need help.  Exactly how would you process this information?  Like I said, I could use CLR, but again, I could use cursors, or functions, or calculated views, etc.  I need help on figuring out the most efficient way of doing this.  Hopefully I don't sound ungrateful (I am grateful), I just want to be clear about what I'm looking for...

Comment: Explain what the computed values are with example data then I can show you what you could do with SQL.

Comment: Each row represents a grid, each grid (2500 bits) can have any number of bits on/off, the 1625625 rows I am dealing with is all unique variations of such a grid.  I am attempting to store the Intersections and Unions of the two grids (binary) for more complex computation later on.  I have put in a working application in my Question which shows sample data (generates it for you on the fly).  I'm happy to provide you with more data, could you let me know exactly what you need?  I'll be glad to whip something up for you...